# Theme the node-create and node-edit template

Tags: php, drupal, templates, coding-style, themes

I'm using drupal 6. I've managed to make a .tpl file for one content type, that is for images in my image gallery. I did that by adding this code in template.php:

```
function artbasic_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return array(
    'galleryimage_node_form' => array(
        'arguments' => array('form' => NULL),
        'template' => 'galleryimage_node_form'
    )
  );
}
```

And then I created galleryimage_node_form.tpl.php, and was good to go. Now it happens so that I want to have other template files for the forms of other content types, for example link_contrib_node_form.tpl.php. I've tried a couple of ways to change this function to include more content types, but I can't figure it out. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function artbasic_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return array(
    'galleryimage_node_form' => array(
        'arguments' => array('form' => NULL),
        'template' => 'galleryimage_node_form'
    ),
    'link_contrib_node_form' => array(
        'arguments' => array('form' => NULL),
        'template' => 'link_contrib_node_form'
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: I've already tried that one. It has no effect, even though it looks like it should work.

Comment: Actually, I did that, and it still didn't work. But today when I started the computer again, it suddenly worked! Perhaps it was some browser cache that prevented before, I don't know. Thanks anyway!